# Realtime DSP algorithms by NI aquisition by PC host

Tags: real-time

Is it possible to implement realtime DSP algorithms on PC using a NI PC acquisition card like NI PCI-4461?

In [A New FXLMS Algorithm with Off-line and On-line Secondary-Path Modeling Scheme for Active Noise Control of Power Transformers](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/7878529/), they run a real time ANC algorithm using a PC.

But my thinking is: PC is not real time. Any application running on it will be non-real-time and maybe interrupted by any other apps or windows services. Then how can these guys run real-time ANC on a PC?

Comment: Depends on how do you define "real-time" ... ?

Comment: @JuhaP Real-time for accoustic active noise cancellation.

Comment: yes, but how much latency is maximum (in ns,ms)? MayhWorks FileExchange lists couple implementation so, you can try if those works for you https://se.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange?q=FXLMS

Answer (score 1):

There is two parts to "real time"

1. **Continuity**: the system can takes in a continuous stream of samples and puts out continuous stream of the same rate. This can go on forever: no samples are lost.
2. **Latency**: that's the delay that the processing introduces and the delay between the input and the output streams.

PCs can certainly do continuous real time processing . Typically PCs don't process one sample at a time, but they buffer up a larger number of samples, process them in one go and than output a full buffer again. That's how they get around the "OS is doing a lot of other stuff at the same time" constraint.

However the buffering introduces a lot of latency (100s or 1000s of samples for audio processing). In many cases this is not a problem and in other cases it is.

The article requires a sign-in that I don't have, so I can't read the full thing. I'm guessing that they have a feed-forward real time processing part that is updated in non-real time using some supervisory process. Feed-back cancellation requires extremely low latency and you can't do it on a PC. Note that they also call it "Control" not "Cancellation", so it may be something different than ANC headsets or ear buds.

Comment: Thx, They're using feedback fxlms and you can use 'sci-hub' to access that paper.